# Get innerHTML of svg-tag result in undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, svg

I'm having some trouble getting the html content of a svg-tag, with javascript in Internet Explorer.

My javascript code is as follow:

```
console.log($('.icon')[0].innerHTML);
```

and my tag in my html document:

```
<svg class="icon"><use>testing</use></svg>
```

This works well in Chrome, Firefox and what have we, but in Internet Explorer I'm left with an undefined error. Is it my mixture of Javascript and jQuery?

How come I can't seem to fetch the content of my svg-tag? I've tried some different things and often I end up with an "SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference"

Help me :) thanks in regards!

Comment: I just tried with document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].innerHTML solely. Still same error of undefined.

Comment: On IE11, I was able to simple append the SVG element to an empty div and get _its_ innterHTML which _does_ return the correct stuff. Includes the `<svg>` tag itself but that isn't to hard to regex out.

Comment: `outerHTML` is also a problem for IE with SVG elements: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29888050/633107.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I found some sort of solution to this. A hacky way perhaps? But works for me atleast.

Instead of getting the raw innerhtml which I can't in IE. I try to get each element-node inside my svg-tag by doing so:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].childNodes;
for (i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    if (element[i].nodeName != '#text') {
        console.log(element[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

How about using [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer). Get yourself the element somehow and then do this...

```
console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(element));
```

Answer (score 15):

Internet Explorer doesn't currently support the `innerHTML` method on SVG Elements. We do however have an issue opened internally to track our consideration of this feature. In the meantime I would explore alternative solutions like the [InnerSVG polyfill](https://github.com/dnozay/innersvg-polyfill) which allegedly works in Internet Explorer 9 and newer.

Comment: Yeah I saw the InnerSVG polyfill. But figured that had to be a simpler way, atleast for my tiny project. I just came up with my answer which fixes it for me.

Comment: The Polyfill is pretty simple; you just reference it and you're done. Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Firefox all proceed to use the same exact code.

Comment: We use an object tag and get our svg from a separate url.  innerSVG doesn't seem to work for that for me.  Does anyone have any ideas about that?

Comment: @Sampson, do you maybe have a link where we can follow the status of the issue to support innerHTML for svg elements?

Comment: Hi @Samspon :-)

Answer (score 3):

The following code will give you the content as string from the given SVG.
It is based on the [great answer of Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28130939/159319).

```
const svgNode = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
const serializer = new XMLSerializer();

const svgContent = Array.prototype.map.call(
  svgNode.childNodes, 
  (child) => serializer.serializeToString(child)
).join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log($('.icon').parent().html());` works fine for me in IE11.

The delivered string starts with a XML declaration
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>`
which seems to be handled as the parent of the svg node.

Comment: To me, this is a suprisingly simple and correct solution. Works for me, thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function () {
    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");
    if(typeof svg["innerHTML"] !== "undefined") {
        return;
    }

    var node = $('<script type="text/svg_template"></script>');

    Object.defineProperty(SVGElement.prototype, 'innerHTML', {
        get: function() {           
            try {
                var childNode = this.firstChild;
                while (childNode) {
                    node.append($.clone(childNode));
                    childNode = childNode.nextSibling;
                }
                return node.html();
            } finally {
                node.empty();
            }
        }
    })
})();
```

set html use:

```
$(svg).html()
```

test on IE11

Comment: perfect for  IE 11. and jquery html() work fine, too

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can append the SVG element to a temporary DIV, take the inner html of that DIV and remove the SVG opening and closing tag from that string.

```js
let parentHtml = $('<div />').append($('svg')).html();
let svgInner = parentHtml.replace(/(<svg)([^<]*|[^>]*)/g, '').replace('</svg>', '');
alert(svgInner);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100"
          style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own innerHTML, like the following [setSVG](https://github.com/yelloxing/image2D/blob/dev/src/core/polyfill.js)：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkYGJ.png)

In fact, you only need to pay attention to two steps: creating the SVG context label and setting properties (with context)

createElementNS and setAttributeNS are two methods you may need！

Common namespaces are as follows:

- svg:http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
- xhtml:http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
- xlink:http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
- xml:http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace
- xmlns:http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/

Comment: test on IE9 & IE11

Answer (score 0):

For actual tags inner content, you can use the following:

```
function innerHTML(anySvgElement) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.appendChild(anySvgElement);
  // Given all SVG tags contain only letters and no numbers, we can strip out the outer tag (the anySvgElement itself)
  return d.innerHTML.replace(/<([a-z]+)[^>]+>(.*)(<\/\1>)/i, '$2')
}
```

For text only inner content, use `node.textContent` instead.