# outerHtml returns undefined for SVG elements in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, svg

Here is my code

```
<svg id="a" height="210" width="400">
  <path id="b" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

i have trigger mouse move event on b

```
   $("#b").hover(function() {
        alert($(this)[0].outerHTML);
    });
```

this was working in chrome but not working in IE how can i solve this..

please find the JSFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/r8v70Lnk/

alert box will show only in chrome but not in IE..

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592417/outerhtml-of-an-svg-element

Comment: maybe you don't need `$(this)[0]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: the exact path can be log (console) in chrome but same sample in IE it can be logged as undefined

Comment: @Filype is right, btw: $(this)[0].outerHTML === this.outerHTML

Comment: try to use this  alert($(this).outerHTML);  Remember ID's are unique so you dont need the "[0]"

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 9):

Dont know if it is a solution for you but i usually do it like:

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('#b'))
```

If you want to parse the string again and insert the node in your document:

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgString, "image/svg+xml")
```

Comment: Evergreen browsers work with the outerHTML spec for SVGs, just not IE and company.  This solution works great though.  Thanks!